# Can we use Bootstrap Icons for Bullet Points?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to know whether we can use `Bootstrap` icons for bullet points (using CSS) or not. I know that we can use `FontAwesome` to do that, but I just want to confirm if it is possible to do that using `Bootstrap`.

While I do know that we can use the following method :

```
<ul>
  <li><i class="bi bi-check"></i> Buy Milk</li>
  <li><i class="bi bi-check"></i> Buy Egg</li>
  <li><i class="bi bi-check"></i> Buy Bread</li>
</ul>
```

I want to do it from CSS, just like this (An example using FontAwesome):

```
<style>
  ul li:before {    
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f00c';
    margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
    color: #f00;
  }
</style>
<ul>
  <li>Buy Milk</li>
  <li>Buy Egg</li>
  <li>Buy Bread</li>
</ul>
```

I want to know how to do it using Bootstrap. If it is not possible then I can use either of the two methods above. If yes, then how do I do it?

Comment: "I only want to know if it is possible or not." Why dont you just try it out?! Or is this question more like a "I dont know how to do it"?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. That was a poor phrasing on my part. I changed it to make it more understandable. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Include the icon stylesheet in the `head` tag or `@import` in css file follow intruction from the [site](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/).
Then in `:before`, you declare `font-family: bootstrap-icons !important;` and `content` with whatever icon you want, ie the hearth icon will have the code as `\F59E` and so on.

```css
div:before {
    content: "\F59E";
    font-family: bootstrap-icons !important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: -.125em;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>+1</div>
```

Comment: I could not get your suggestion to work. Can you please give me more detailed example?

Answer (score 2):

My answer might get you some more flexibility. You can use custom counters for any style type.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: thumbs;
}

@counter-style thumbs {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols:   ;
  suffix: " ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><i class="bi bi-check"></i> Buy Milk</li>
  <li><i class="bi bi-check"></i> Buy Egg</li>
  <li><i class="bi bi-check"></i> Buy Bread</li>
</ul>
```

you can add any type of symbols you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer did give me more flexibility. Instead of the symbols, I just used the css code for "check icon" and it worked as intended. I got to learn new css property thanks to you.